# Session missmatch in ADFS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wif, adfs

I use an ADFS STS to log into my application.

Roles and users are working properely most of the time, but on somes pages, I get some users mismatch : suddenly, the username on the up right corner of the screen is not the right one (it's another user that is logged in at the same time).

Do you have any clue of what I should check ?

Thanks.

Comment: First thought is caching and cache-variance.  I'm thinking that that cache control is set to public, and no other vary-bys means you could get a response from a different session.

Comment: Hi,I suspected caching at first because I was using OutputCache for some data. I then removed all OutputCache statements. I even used <caching enabled="false" enableKernelCache="false" />

Comment: You marking HTML content responses explicitly as private?

Comment: Hi, how do I do that please ?

Comment: Moved comment into answer - let us know how you get on...

Answer (score 0):

** comment moved into an answer **

First thought is caching and cache-variance. I'm thinking that that cache control is either not set, or set to public, and no other vary-bys means you could get a response from a different session.

If you're not setting private headers in your response, you should be explicit:

```
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
```

There's a bunch of different ways to wrap e.g. attributes to make more MVC-like.
MSDN docs here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.cachecontrol.aspx